# Authorization failed: Please connect to iTunes

Tags: iphone

I always get this message whenever I tried to download an app from the appstore, some peoople tell me that this is due to the dynamically changing Terms of Use from Apple, how can I accept the Terms of Use. Tried everything else but jailbreak.

Comment: Update your Itunes and all connected things like flash player, silverlight, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accept the terms I believe you have to sign in to iTunes, go to your account by clicking on your email in the top right corner and scroll down to the terms of service.